# SQL Server - Creating a trend based on property used during time

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple task: I need to see what payment modes have been in use and which ones are no longer being used. Here is my schema:

```
SELECT [PAY_MODE_ID]
      ,[BILL_DATE]    
  FROM [dbo].[BILL_INFO]
```

All payment modes are:

```
 1, Cash
 2, Cheque
 3, Debit
 4, Free
 5, Credit Card
 6, Advanced Cash
 7, Cash Card
 8, Visa Electron
 9, e-Pay
10, Bank Transfer
11, Third-Party Collections
```

I want to see a usage trend as How many of each payment mode was used per month per year. I'm hoping to see which mode is dying.

Comment: Your problem isn't so simple and will require analytical or reporting tools other than the database, such as Tableau or qlikview where you can do linear regressions or the such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first bit if you're pivoting in something like MS Excel:

```
--Build sample dataset
CREATE TABLE #TMP([PAY_MODE_ID] TINYINT,[BILL_DATE] DATE)
GO
INSERT INTO #TMP
SELECT CAST(RAND()*11 AS TINYINT),DATEADD(DD,CAST(RAND()*365 AS INT),'20180101')
GO 10000

SELECT 
    [PAY_MODE_ID]
    ,MONTH([BILL_DATE]) AS [MonthNo]    
    ,DATENAME(Month,[BILL_DATE]) AS [Month]    
    ,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
 FROM #TMP
GROUP BY
    [PAY_MODE_ID]
    ,MONTH([BILL_DATE]) 
    ,DATENAME(Month,[BILL_DATE])
```

If you want to pivot the data in the SQL environment and not in a third party tool, use something like this:

```
SELECT
    [PAY_MODE_ID]
    ,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        [PAY_MODE_ID]
        ,DATENAME(Month,[BILL_DATE]) AS [Month]    
        ,COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM #TMP
    GROUP BY
        [PAY_MODE_ID]
        ,DATENAME(Month,[BILL_DATE]) 
    ) D
        PIVOT
            (SUM(Cnt) FOR [Month] IN (January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December)) M
```

Answer (score 1):

With the information provided (some sample data would have really helped) I would suggest to try this query -

```
SELECT COUNT([PAY_MODE_ID])
      ,[PAY_MODE_ID]    
  FROM [dbo].[BILL_INFO]
GROUP BY [PAY_MODE_ID], MONTH([BILL_DATE]), YEAR([BILL_DATE])
```

This would group on all the available payment modes based on the number of times used.